# How to parse a date and only the date from a `date_string` in python?

Tags: python, parsing, date

I have a variable containing a string from which I want to parse the date. I tryed this:

```
import datetime
date_string = "July 2010"
parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%B %Y")
print parsed_date
# datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0))
```

I assume the *1* is added by datetime, because a date must have a *day*?
But why are there two zeroes? I assume this shall be the time? Is there a way to avoid the time? I only want the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call [`.date()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) on the datetime object. This returns a `date` object.

```
In [5]: dt
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0)
In [6]: dt.date()
Out[6]: datetime.date(2010, 7, 1)
```

For your other subquestions:

- Yes, the `0, 0` is the time.
- A date always has year, month and day (with `1 <= day <= 31`).

Comment: Just to complete my questions and eliminate my doubts. :-) Are my assumptions right?