# How to ignore the time while converting string to date?

Tags: python

I want to convert '2011-10-13' to a date object representing the same. I use strptime but it includes the time, which I dont need. How to best avoid this?

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-10-13", "%Y-%m-%d")

print d

2011-10-13 00:00:00

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date and only the date from a `date_string` in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000784/how-to-parse-a-date-and-only-the-date-from-a-date-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the .date() method:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2011-10-13", "%Y-%m-%d")
print d.date()
>> 2011-10-13
```

Comment: oh wow! Why was I spending so much time on this:)? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a time component, use [`date`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date), not `datetime`.